# Search help exits: How to set initial parameters on the Search Help select-options, and customize the data selection? (both, not just one of these)

Tags: user-interface, abap

My problem is this:

I want to trigger a search help programatically.
I want to populate the initial select-options screen with default values (and set some as non-editable).

After the user choses aditional parameters (or changes the existing ones) I want to be able to implement the data selection logic myself.

My approach is using a search-help exit.

I've managed to fill in the initial select-options parameters, but then I couldn't modify the data selection logic. For this I filled the `SHLP_TAB[]-INTERFACE` table with data, and kept the `CALLCONTROL-STEP = 'SELONE'.`

I've managed to be able to be able to modify the data selection logic, by setting the `CALLCONTROL-STEP = 'PRESEL'.` but then I couldn't populate the initial screen with data either by filling the `SHLP` structure (`INTERFACE` table of it) or the `SHLP_TAB` table (same `INTERFACE`) component.

I want to both populate the initial screen, and control the data selection. (How) can this be done?

**[EDIT]**
**SOLVED**
The problem was that I was using an exit function module for a collective search help that I was calling.
This works differently from an elementary search help exit function.

The collective search help does indeed supply the parameters (thorugh the defined binding) for the `PRESEL` event, but the `SELECT` event is then performed in the elementary search help.
The Collective search help `SELECT` event is apparently called after skipping the `PRESEL` events of the elementary search helps, so that is why one should be careful when to use exit functions for either the Collective search help, or the elementary search help.

Comment: Could you please add some example code so that we can reproduce your issues?

Comment: In the mean time i solved the issue. The problem isn't visible in the code. It's in the fact that i was using an exit for a collective search help, and not for the elementary shlp. Thx.